# How to use recycleview inside an alertdialog in fragment

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog

I was having problem showing items in a `recycleView` inside an `alertdialog` in a `Fragment`

The items that I was showing are the filenames.

This is the stucture of my design that I was doing >Activity > Fragment > AlertDialog

In my AlertDialog I am inflating a new layout to get my custom design where I can put event to open a storage and get the files multiple or single.

Below the code to Open files only

`getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 1001);` It means I am getting the result in my activity overriding `OnActivityResult`

```
private void browseDocuments(){

    String[] mimeTypes =
            {"application/msword","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", // .doc & .docx
                    "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation", // .ppt & .pptx
                    "application/vnd.ms-excel","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", // .xls & .xlsx
                    "text/plain",
                    "application/pdf",
                    "application/zip"};

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        intent.setType(mimeTypes.length == 1 ? mimeTypes[0] : "*/*");
        if (mimeTypes.length > 0) {
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
        }
    } else {
        String mimeTypesStr = "";
        for (String mimeType : mimeTypes) {
            mimeTypesStr += mimeType + "|";
        }
        intent.setType(mimeTypesStr.substring(0,mimeTypesStr.length() - 1));
    }

    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 1001);

}
```

Below code adding filesNames to arraysList in OnActivityResult in my Activity which is perfectly running and getting the files

```
 if (requestCode == 1001){

        FileAdapter = new fileAdapter(announcement_fragment.FileListName);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater(); //Is this correct?
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_announcement, null);
        RecyclerView listFiles = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.containerForFiles);
        listFiles.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(dialogView.getContext()));
        listFiles.setHasFixedSize(true);
        listFiles.setAdapter(FileAdapter);

       if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            //Upload Mutliple
            if(data.getClipData() !=null){
                announcement_fragment.FileListName.clear();

               // Toast.makeText(this,"Mutliple",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
                int i=0;
                while (i<count){
                    announcement_fragment.FileListName.add(getFileName(File));
                    FileAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    i++;
                }
            }else if(data.getData() != null){
                announcement_fragment.FileListName.add(getFileName(File));
                FileAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }else{
                //Do nothing
            }
      }

 }
```

I call and set adapter in my activity inside `OnActivityResult` (see above code) to notify the adapter but it doesnt work, next I dont know what could be done to achieve it, Where hould I put the adapter to trigger the recycleview items

Answer (score 0):

You could either try using ListView first, then see if it works.
The problem could be with your code.
Try using `ListView`, if it works, then try `RecycleView`.